# Is "On XXX of YYY" a good thesis title?

Tags: thesis

I've seen many theses with long long title.

I understand that can help to narrow down the scope of the thesis.

Yet, I was recently asked to think of the title of my thesis, and I don't like those long long titles.

Is something in the form of "On XXX of YYY" a good title?

For instance,

- "On the uncountability of real numbers"
- "On the identification of biological systems"

I think this can make the thesis rather straightforward. Is such a title specific enough to attract the intended audience?

Comment: Good by what standards? What did your supervisor say? This question just reads like an invitation to discussion and opinion.

Comment: I always thought that titles like this sound archaic (for instance On the Origin of Species). You can just publish "The Origin of Species" and it will be just as fine, and shorter. That said, I occasionally entertain myself with naming a paper like that, just for fun.

Comment: I'd think from the readers' point of view: would the title likely attract your intended audience (sensitive enough)? And would the title likely discourage unintended audience (specific enough)? Straightforward does not mean short; you can have a long title that is still vague.

Comment: Not so much for theses, but for papers there is also the added factor that I am convinced that having a generic, non-descript, or even plain misleading paper title can cost you readers, citations, and impact.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific (Thanks, Penguin_Knight for the suggestion.) @Costa, if this is not what you intended to ask, feel free to re-edit!

Comment: @xLeitix: it will cost the person citations of their *thesis*?

Comment: @OswaldVeblen That's why I said *"not so much for theses, but for papers"*.

Answer (score 8):

The title of a work is the first thing that people will use to decide whether to read it or not.  You want it to say as clearly and lucidly as possible what it is that you have contributed.  If you title something "On XXX of YYY", then that says you've done a loosely coupled collection of investigations regarding the relationship of XXX and YYY.  If, however, the important conclusion of your thesis is more specific, it's good to say that in your title.

To make up an example, compare:

- "On the diet of Antarctic seals": this document studied diet exhaustively, and came up with very thorough data but no particularly big surprises.
- "Antarctic seal diet dependent on frozen pizza": this document studied diet, and found something rather bizarre that clearly needs more study.

In sum: short is good, but unnecessarily vague is bad.

Answer (score 4):

I personally don't care for this style of title.  Seeing a title like "On the cromulence of blobs" makes me wonder: What exactly *about* the cromulence of blobs is the author investigating?  Why doesn't she just tell me?  It tends to leave me less piqued than frustrated, and gives me the subconscious suggestion that rather than producing a specific result, the paper is just going to ramble on about blobs and their cromulence.

But in general, for choosing a title: the first question is, what kind of thesis did you write?  Some theses (especially doctoral) are **original** and present new results, others (especially undergraduate and sometimes masters) are **expository** and simply explore existing results.

For an **original thesis**, my advice would be to choose a rather specific title that accurately describes your results, even if it is long.  I would use the following rule of thumb to evaluate potential titles: look at all the papers you know that contain closely related work (hopefully you have cited all of them, so all you should need to do is open your bibliography).  For each of them, ask yourself: **Does my title make it clear that what I did is different from what's in this other paper?**  If not, your title is not specific enough.  Other researchers doing related work will want to be able to tell at a glance whether your thesis is likely to address the question they have in mind.

For an **expository** thesis, a more general title is fine: just state the topic that you wrote about.  People are unlikely to come looking for such a thesis with a specific question in mind; they may read your thesis more for a general overview of the topic.

Comment: Mmmm...cromulent blobs...

Comment: I don't think the title of a thesis or paper often does this - the abstract is more important for stating the key results. I view the title more as a sort of decoration: a way for the author to express themselves, or to draw an analogy with other papers.

Answer (score 0):

That name made me curious and i opened the Question. But i did not got from name what is it about.

If thesis is about to make people curious, then go for it. but if you want a name that one is real representation of your thesis. Then choose an alternate.

Comment: I would argue that the main target audience of a thesis is forced to read it anyway, so there is no point in making a "catchy" title. On the other hand, I think these titles can indeed be informative, specially if you are in the field (think "On the use of linear kernel SVM for OCR"),

Comment: YES, but attract them with main article would be better rather than curiosity, and every one is not curious. That was my suggestion you have full right to offence.

Comment: OCR= Optical Character Recognition ? right? if I am from this field i would like to read it. as i have also worked in Hand Writing Recognition. 
But if OCR is unknown to me. Curiosity cant be cause to read.